# What is pgv_si and pgv_pvi

Tags: php, cookies

I'm using PHPV7, I found there is `pgv_si` and `pgv_pvi`. I can't find them from PHP.net official website. Anyone knows what is that?

The code is below:

`var_dump('cookie', $_COOKIE);`

I understand it is generated by cookie, but I don't know what is that for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just some variables in cookies, set by server. Please read some documentation on cookies, that does not have any connection to PHP itself.

Answer (score 0):

They are set for the Tencent QQ login service authentication.

There are four vars related with that:
**pgv_pvi,pgv_si,pgv_pvid, pgv_info=ssid=xxx**

You can read more at blog posts below:
https://blog.csdn.net/frykool/article/details/11833335
http://www.cnblogs.com/shawnye/p/6376400.html